# Spring Security Error for Authentication Bearer

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, runtime-error

I am facing below error while doing the Azure AD authentication in Spring 3.0.4.

```
Receiver class com.azure.spring.cloud.autoconfigure.aad.implementation.webapi.validator.AadJwtIssuerValidator does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2TokenValidatorResult validate(org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2Token)' of interface org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2TokenValidator.
```

Spring Security Version is 6.0.3.

I have tried adding the necessary dependencies which are mentioned below,

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter-active-directory</artifactId>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
   <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter-data-cosmos</artifactId>
   <version>4.7.0</version>
   <exclusions>
<exclusion>
  <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
  <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
</exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependencyManagement>
 <dependencies>
   <dependency>
   <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-dependencies</artifactId>
<version>${spring-cloud-azure.version}</version>
<type>pom</type>
<scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
<exclusions>
<exclusion>
<groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
</exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
```

I am expecting it to authenticate correctly, because the same dependencies worked in Spring 2.7.9.

Comment: The exception is telling you that the `AadJwtIssuerValidator` does not correctly implements `OAuth2TokenValidator`. Please make sure that you are using versions that match of those dependencies